# Adding hours to coutdown counter

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am very new to the javascript and I need make this function to count down to a specific hour. The current code count down to the start of the day and I need to add a couple of hour more. How am I gonna do this?

```
<script>
//cd counter//
var current = "<b class='cdb'>&nbsp;0д.</b> : <b class='cdb'>&nbsp;0ч.</b> : <b class='cdb'>&nbsp;0м.</b> : <b class='cdb'>&nbsp;00с.</b><br />";
var montharray = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
function countdown(yr,m,d){
    theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d
    var today=new Date();
    var todayy=today.getYear();
if (todayy < 1000)
    todayy+=1900 
    var todaym=today.getMonth() 
    var todayd=today.getDate() 
    var todayh=today.getHours() 
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes() 
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds() 
    var todaystring=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec 
    futurestring=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr 
    dd=Date.parse(futurestring)-Date.parse(todaystring) 
    dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1)
    dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1)
    dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1)
    dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1)
if(dday<0&&dhour<0&&dmin<0&&dsec<1){ 
    document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML = current;
    return 
} else 
    document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML = "<b class='cdb'>"+dday+"д.</b> : <b class='cdb'>"+dhour+"ч.</b> : <b class='cdb'>"+dmin+"м.</b> : <b class='cdb'>"+dsec+"с.</b><br />";
    setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday)",1000) 
}
countdown(2013,11,8);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to just add the number of hours you want to your dhour variable.

```
dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1) + numHours
```

A more robust way of doing it is adding all the same information to your futurestring:

```
futurestring=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hour+":"+min+":"+sec
```

Of course, then you'd need to set `hour`, `min`, and `sec`.